# How can we call the Function of desktop application via chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have one c# desktop application which will be interacting with Database. I want to call the function of that application in my chrome extension. Is there any way of doing the same?

Comment: The only more-or-less direct way is [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) API. The alternative is to add a web API to your desktop app so the extension could use XHR/fetch to localhost.

Comment: @wOxxOm Will it be possible to give an example for using XHR. I was trying to use the XHR by directly calling the local js file but that is not working.

Comment: Like I said, first you need to add a web API to your desktop app. I don't know C# but there should be lots of ways to do it and it should be possible to find a tutorial easily because C# is a popular language.